# animated anchor scrolling method for iOS with iScroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iscroll, iscroll4

Im using [iScoll.js](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) to help with scrolling animations on iOS. Basically it uses hardware accelerated CSS properties to move the content, not traditional scrolling.

iScoll is working well but I'm also trying to implement a smooth scrolling anchor solution.

It works fine on desktop but the problem is that I can't workout how to retrieve the correct offset value to pass to the iScoll Instance. I feel like im super close to a solution:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
    isMobileWebkit = /WebKit/.test(ua) && /Mobile/.test(ua);

if (isMobileWebkit) {
      iScrollInstance = new iScroll('wrapper');
}


$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
               if (target.length) {
                   if (isMobileWebkit) {
                       iScrollInstance.refresh();
/* issue here with "target.position.top" = "undefined" */
                       iScrollInstance.scrollTo(0, target.position.top, 1000);
                   }else{
                        $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                   }
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

full demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Wccev/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but it seems iScroll.js didn't like jQuery in the scrollTo function. So setting the variable ahead of time seemed to help. I also had to work out the correct offset because of the way iScroll moves a div not the screen.

If anyone needs it, this jQuery should help with smooth scrolling anchors on IOs devices provided you setup iScroll correctly:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
    isMobileWebkit = /WebKit/.test(ua) && /Mobile/.test(ua);

if (isMobileWebkit) {
    $('html').addClass('mobile');
}   

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
               if (target.length) {
                   if (isMobileWebkit) {
                        scrollOffset = $('#scroller').position().top;
                        targetOffset = target.offset().top;
                        iScrollInstance.refresh();
                        iScrollInstance.scrollTo(0, -(targetOffset-scrollOffset), 1000);
                   }else{
                        $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                   }
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```